# Print HTML Progress Bar using Python

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am trying to print the following HTML to a page using a Python script. I am following the example here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_progressbar

I am unable to get the following code to work:

```
from lxml import etree, html

document_root = html.fromstring("<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> <body> <div class="w3-border"> <div class="w3-grey" style="height:24px;width:20%"> </div> </div> </body> </html>")
print(etree.tostring(document_root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape doublequotes

```
from lxml import etree, html    

str = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> <body> <div class="w3-border"> <div class="w3-grey" style="height:24px;width:20%"> </div> </div> </body> </html>'
document_root = html.fromstring(str)
print(etree.tostring(document_root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

executing this script,

```
$ python test.py
<html> <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/> </head><body> <div class="w3-border"> <div class="w3-grey" style="height:24px;width:20%"> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

UPDATE:

below command will let you to see output instantly (i assume you are on a *nix machine and have firefox installed. or start any other browser)

```
$ python test.py >> index.html && python -m SimpleHTTPServer && firefox localhost:8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017 11:34:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```